# Запретить Unity исключать файлы из билда под Android при включенном proguard'е

Tags: java, android, unity3d, proguard

Есть плагин нативный, классы из которого должны войти в итоговый билд. Но при включенном proguard'е и минимификации эти классы исключаются из билда.

Можно было бы в **Plugins\Android\proguard-user.txt** дописать:

```
-keep class com.unnynet.webview.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.unnynet.webview.**
```

Но мы этот плагин даём другим разработчикам, просить их создавать этот файлик и включать его в настройках при сборке - очень неудобное решение.

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Можно создать файл своих правил в своем репозитории. А клиент должен будет прописать consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro' или другое какое - то название